# How to make a primary key start from 001?

Tags: mysql, database

I need the primary key to start from 001 in MySQL table. I used the following code to do so but it didn't work. It avoids 00 and starts from 1.

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 001;
```

Is it possible to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is 001 different from 1? Both represent the number that comes after zero. When outputting (in PHP, .NET, rails, etc.) just format the number, with e.g. `printf('%03d', $number)`

Comment: Sorry, I din't get you.

Comment: 001 and 1 are the same number. They both are _one_. If you need to output the number in a specific format, do it when outputting

Answer (score 2):

Auto_increment fields must be an integer field. So it is not possible to do what you want. Because integer values can not have leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

What is `001` is this int with leading zeros?

try this:

```
create table x(
   id INT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key
);
```

In `MySQL` the `(5)` next to the int means values will be returned as 5 positions, ZEROFILL means those 5 positions will be filled with 0. e.g. result will be something like '00001', '00002' etc.

Is not clear for me, if `PHP` or another language will keep those leading zeroes. If not, you can use something like `sprintf` to format them:

```
<?php
$id = sprintf("%05d", $db->id);
?>
```

Please update the question for clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for your effort I've already solved it. Recently I'm facing another problem. Please check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179148/how-to-insert-and-retrive-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-in-mysql-database

Comment: when you solve it, you might share the result to help next person who looks the question :)