# How to insert and retrive data from one table to another table in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two Tables Page and Upload

PAGE:

```
page_id,   page_name,   page_parent 
( 4,   test,   0)
( 5,   test-sub,   4)
( 6,   test-sub2,   4)
```

UPLOAD:

```
upload_id,   upload_name,   upload_root
(1,    test,   4)
(2,    test-sub,   4)
(3,   test-sub2,   4)
```

I was quite successful to get the page_id into upload_root but got problem when the page has submenu and is entered into page_parent.

### My insert command goes like this:

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
$root = $_POST['root'];
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_upload VALUES ('' , \"$name\",  \"$root\")";

$root = $_POST['page_id'];?>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div>Name:   <input name="title" type="text" size="50"/></div> 
<input name="page_id" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo"$page_id"; ?>"
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload" class="upload"/>
</form>
```

### My fetch command goes like this:

```
$fetch_sql = "SELECT upload_id, upload_name, upload_root from tbl_upload WHERE upload_root = \"$page_id\"";
```

I cannot get the correct url of the pages. I'm not getting the correct words to describe my problem. But what I exatly want is to retrive the exact value of page_id (which is auto increment) into upload_id if not possible then to upload_root.

### What I want to do is :

UPLOAD:

```
upload_id,   upload_name,   upload_root
(4,   test,   4)
(5,   test-sub,   4)
(6,   test-sub2,   4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
$name =  $_POST['title'];
$pageid = $_POST['page_id'];
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_upload (upload_id, upload_name, upload_root) VALUES ('".$pageid."','".$name."','')";
mysql_query($insert_sql);
}
?>
<form action="your_page.php?submit=yes" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div>Name:   <input type="text" name="title" size="50"></div> 
<input type="hidden" name="page_id" value= "<?php echo $page_id; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload" class="upload">
</form>
```

Obviously, insert the name of page where it says 'your_page.php'

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please look up how to implement PDO for future projects.